# Refresh the UI data when a button clicked in a web socket connection

Tags: flutter, dart, http, websocket, stream

Im updating a function in my project that uses web sockets. Think of location information list in the UI screen to be shown and each location data is fetched using a public/common web socket connection. Idea is to lower the execution time when retrieving updates for multiple locations (for each location) when I hit a fetch button.

let's say there were 7 locations in the list with some data for each of list item. I choose one location and navigate to a UI screen of that location details shown. I will have an update button in that UI screen where when I click on it the UI screen details must fetch the latest data from the web socket stream and then update the UI screen accordingly.

How can I achieve something like this with dart and flutter.
Can anyone provide me with a code snippet and steps ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: im expecting a code solution :) if its not too bold to ask.